# How to fetch data from a REST API in serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I am new to serverless. I want to fetch data from google. I am using Google Custom Search engine. Although I got results when I run locally. But when I deploy to AWS Lambda I am getting "Internal Server Error".  Can anyone help me to fix the issue?

```
'use strict';

var request = require('request');

module.exports.get = (event, context, callback) => {

request('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Serverless+AWS+Lambda&cx=xxxxxxxxxxx&key=API_key&num=10', function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {


      callback(null, response);

      console.log(body);

    } else {
      console.warn(error);
    }

  });

};
```

I want a json output. I would like to save that result

Answer (score 0):

Internal Server Error mostly points out that your lambda code could not be executed correctly. Did you pack all your dependencies (node_modules) within the ZIP file you provide to AWS lambda (e.g. request ?)

Comment: I have uploaded the required dependencies. I don't know what is the error.

Comment: Could you provide the CloudWatch logs for this if there are any? How do you invoke it? Directly or via API Gateway?